# Double nomenclature of molecular orbitals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, atoms, orbitals, molecules

I'm studying molecules from Brandsen-Joachain's book: "Physics of atoms and molecules". In chapter 9 he talks about molecular orbitals, and then he specifically talks about them for homonuclear diatomic molecules saying that you can construct them with the LCAO approximation.

What confuses me is the notation that the book uses to indicate those orbitals in what the book calls "correlation diagram". It says:

> It should be noted that molecular orbitals can either be labelled by the separated or the united atom limits. For example, the lowest odd orbital $\Phi_u$ can be designated in the separated atom limit as $\sigma^*_u1s$ (as was done above) or in the united atom limit as $2p\sigma_u^*$. We recall that the repulsive (or antibonding) orbitals are distinguished from the attractive (or bonding) orbitals by the addition of an asterisk.

Now, I am a bit confused about what those notations mean (I also put the image of the correlation diagram where they are used. The molecular orbitals, according to the book, are constructed as
$$\Phi(\vec r)=N\left[ u_a(\vec r-\vec r_A)\pm u_b(\vec r-\vec r_B) \right]$$
where $N$ is a normalization constant, $u_a$ and $u_b$ are atomic orbitals and $\vec r_A$ and $\vec r_B$ is the positions of the nuclei. So, what do those notations mean exactly? How do they tell me which atomic orbitals or which combinations were used to construct the molecular orbital?

[image]